# Is this a complex sentence?

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences, transitive-verbs

In a comment on a previous post, a member explained to me:

> that a complex transitive verb (or clause) is defined as one that has a direct object and a complement that specifically relates to the object, called an object complement. The object complement may be a noun phrase (They elected him president) or an adjective phrase (They painted the house red).

On that basis, are the following sentences complex clauses (and is the last one a complex ditransitive)?

1) He was impressive as he stood up there on the platform.

2) No one in this room considered me an individual.

3) I couldn’t get it out of my mind that something was wrong.

For example, sentence (2) seems to have an object complement *an individual* which describes a potential description of *me*.

Comment: 1) is complex, 2) is simple, 3) is complex

Comment: Thanks BillJ. Regarding number 2: is it because she/he already knew the answer?

Comment: It's because there is only one clause in 2), i.e. the sentence as a whole. .A complex sentence contains an independent clause and at least one subordinate clause.

Comment: Thank you. Last year you told me that: You must understand that a complex transitive verb (or clause) is defined as one that has a direct object and a complement that specifically relates to the object, called an object complement. The object complement may be a noun phrase (They elected him president) or an adjective phrase (They painted the house red). – BillJ Nov 26 '16 at 9:13 - I thought of ''an individual'' as objet complement. that's why :(

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, I guess so, although generally the community doesn't like more than one question being asked at once. It's not really clear what the square brackets are supposed to indicate.

Comment: @andrew Thanks a lot. The square brackets are no longer here. :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think Mona took the bits inside to be object complements?

Comment: @BillJ In the sentence: He was impressive as he stood up there on the platform. In my viewpoint, UP THERE is an adverb of place. Since we are in presence of a transitive complex sentence, can we consider UP THERE as a direct object?

Comment: You're right that it's a locative adjunct. But locatives can't normally be direct objects -- only noun phrases can fill that role. (I say "normally" because there is a minor exception, but it has no bearing here).

Comment: @BillJ We know that transitive complex sentences can be written in the passive voice, but I can't do it here, because, when I write down the sentence in the passive voice, I ended up without UP (which is not a particle here); There he was standing on the platform. Could you please clarify these point please, one last time?

Comment: No, what I said was that locatives **can't** normally be direct objects -- only noun phrases can be objects, and "up there" is a preposition phrase, not an NP. It's not a complex transitive sentence, but a complex intransitive one because there's no object.

Comment: @BillJ I think, I get it now. So only: I couldn’t get it out of my mind that something was wrong, could have been a ''transitive complex sentence'' Because a direct object can be a noun but also pronoun that identifies what or who receives the action of a transitive verb in a clause or sentence.

Comment: Yes, it's a transitive clause -- it has a direct object, "it".

Comment: @BillJ please, I need to clarify something that kept me thinking. When the pronoun IT is an object of a transitive verb, It is always a referential IT, right? I mean we can't have a non-referential IT.

Comment: I've retyped my message - it had a typo. Generally that is true, but not always. For example, it is not referential in 'object extraposition' constructions like "I find it disappointing that he gave up" and "She considers it quite outrageous that I didn't consult her". In those two examples, "it" is object of the verb, but it is non-referential -- just a dummy element, serving the syntactic purpose of filling the object position.

Comment: It's hard to understand, in the sentence, ''She considers it quite outrageous that I didn't consult her''  to me 'it' refers to, 'I didn't consult her'  does that include all it  'object extraposition'? Because, if its the case, I couldn’t get it out of my mind that something was wrong, and the juxtaposition (...) made it clear that they thought of both of us as (...) contains both a non-referential it.

Comment: ''it is referential because the earlier does provide a referential interpretation/clarification of the pronoun''  What if the information comes after the personal pronoun like in those sentences: I couldn’t get it out of my mind that something was wrong, and the juxtaposition (...) made it clear that they thought of both of us as (...) I'm asking because you said 'earlier' I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: Another typo! "It" is related to the extraposed object, but we don't talk of "it" as being referential in extraposition constructions. Incidentally, the same applies with subject extraposition, as in "It would be a mistake to give up now". Again "it" is not referential, but just a dummy element serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position. On the other hand, when "it" is a personal pronoun as in for example "His new car, I don't like **it** at all", it is referential because the earlier element does provide a referential interpretation/clarification of the pronoun.

Comment: It's the same in "**It** is hard work, picking fruit all day". This time the later element provide a referential interpretation/clarification of the pronoun. Thus in both left and right dislocation the pronoun is referential.